# flutter AdBlock WebView?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to block ads in an flutter WebView? I am building app that lets users browse web pages, but need to block ads. Its basically a custom browser, but I need to get rid of ads.

Comment: Not sure WebView should be used as a custom browser.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Did you find something? I just need to block pop ups.

Comment: As Julien Lachal said, WebView is **not** a custom browser. In fact, on Android, WebView uses Google Chrome behind the scenes. Check this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview, where it literally says "Android WebView is a system component powered by Chrome"

Answer (score 3):

The `webview_flutter` plugin, currently, doesn't offer such feature.

However, to block ads, you can use the [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin (I'm the author). It offers the content blocking feature through the `ContentBlocker` class!

I have written an article that explains it in more detail and can be found [here](https://medium.com/@pichillilorenzo/webview-content-blockers-flutter-inappwebview-6-faba4d61c294?source=friends_link&sk=707043bdd267f2292e0753b87b816191).

Also, I have created a full project example on GitHub [here (webview_ad_blocker)](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_examples/tree/main/webview_ad_blocker) that uses the `ContentBlocker` class to block the loading of ads, such as Google Ads.

[image: Android ads content blocker example]
[image: iOS ads content blocker example]

Answer (score 2):

navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
return NavigationDecision.prevent;}

I added that to the Webview to prevent navigation to other screens in case they accidentally click on those ads.

```
WebView(
      initialUrl: widget.url,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
      },
      javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
        _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
      ].toSet(),
      navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
        return NavigationDecision.prevent;
     
      },
      onPageStarted: (String url) {
        print('Page started loading: $url');
      },
      onPageFinished: (String url) {
        print('Page finished loading: $url');
      },
      gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
    );
```