# How to block ads in Webview Flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, webview, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to develop an app in which I am trying to get a dynamic video URL from a website using webview but the issue is whenever the ads start popping I can't get the URL in webview. I am using a JavaScript channel in webview though which I get the specific element when the page finishes loading but when ads start popping I couldn't get that element is there any solution for it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can try to use my [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin, which offers the content-blocking feature through the `ContentBlocker` class!. Check my other [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74611660/4637638).

Answer (score 0):

you can just block it the website not in app

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I didn't understand your point can you explain it ?

Comment: ads work in the website not in application (webview)

Comment: How do i block them in the website is there any way to make it work. sorry if i am asking noob question but i really need it for my project