# How to block ads in a flutter webView ( web page in mobile app )

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I have made an app using the webview_flutter plugin, the webviews leads to a URL that streams a video. But there's a new advertisement pop-up every time I enter this webview. I'd be glad if anyone could provide a solution to prevent this from happening. I find a way to do that but for android native (check the link for more information : [github repository](https://github.com/MonsterTechnoGits/WebViewAdblock-Library)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter AdBlock WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158961/flutter-adblock-webview)

Comment: Check the dupe i posted

Comment: Hi @ElPrimo I already checked that post unfortunately it's didn't worked for me. any suggestions.

Comment: Please specify what have you tried from the post.

Comment: You can't do that in Flutter. WebView is not a custom webview. It is powered by Chrome. So you can't block ads. Although you can disable clicks on the ads so that whenever the user clicks on them nothing happens. There are many GitHub repositories. Try one of them out

Comment: You can disable clicks on ad by refering the post in the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't do that
the only way is "Disable JavaScript" parameter on Webview by
javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

Answer (score 0):

To block ads, you can use the [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin (I'm the author). It offers the content blocking feature through the `ContentBlocker` class!

I have written an article that explains it in more detail and can be found [here](https://medium.com/@pichillilorenzo/webview-content-blockers-flutter-inappwebview-6-faba4d61c294?source=friends_link&sk=707043bdd267f2292e0753b87b816191).

Also, I have created a full project example on GitHub [here (webview_ad_blocker)](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_examples/tree/main/webview_ad_blocker) that uses the `ContentBlocker` class to block the loading of ads, such as Google Ads.

[image: Android ads content blocker example]
[image: iOS ads content blocker example]